# How to calculate, and map a array from one certain field

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I created a simple mongoose query to get a array of info, and then sort it.

```
const stats_m = await monthlySessions.find({}).sort({ month: 1 });
```

And the response looks something along the lines of this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 60c3dce8f27cc56bbcf20e94,
    steamID: '76561199105033642',
    displayName: 'username',
    LastJoinDate: 'Sat Jun 12 2021 01:00:04 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
    LastLeaveDate: 'Sat Jun 12 2021 01:00:07 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
    SessionTime: 14,
    UID: '60a6572b98a160df4ffc8b20',
    month: 5,
    year: '2021',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 60c3ddda65e2073ea162cdfa,
    displayName: 'username',
    LastJoinDate: 'Sat Jun 12 2021 01:00:04 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
    LastLeaveDate: 'Sat Jun 12 2021 01:00:07 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
    SessionTime: 14,
    UID: '60a6572b98a160df4ffc8b20',
    month: 6,
    year: '2021',
    __v: 0,
    steamID: '76561199105033642'
  }
]
```

now what i need to do is get every object with the same value of field `month`, and add `SessionTime` together, then create a new object out of it, that will only contain `month`, `year`, `SessionTime`

How would i go about doing this ?

Comment: Please post the input and expected output as text.

Comment: @iota okay, i updated the post with the expected output as text.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: The output is the array of objects i had pasted into the post. However, it will contain more objects with diffrent values as time progresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregate with [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month: "$month",
        year: "$year"
      },
      SessionTime: {
        $sum: "$SessionTime"
      },
  
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      month: "$_id.month",
      year: "$_id.year",
      SessionTime: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J370CoLJZWS)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually don't know much about Mongoose, but I helped a bloke the other day with a similar data filtering process from a Mongoose model and getting to the data was tricky. We ended up having to use [lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) - like I have below.

You may not need that, so the snippet below has the code to filter your objects into the result you want. It uses `reduce()` to keep track of and combine records. You didnt specify this - but I combined based on the *year and month* - where as you only specified the month. Let me know if I need to adjust that. I also added an extra object in there to show how it adds up `SessionTime`

```
const stats_m = await monthlySessions.find({})
  .lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
    return Object.values(docs.reduce((b, a) => {
  let key = a.month + '' + a.year
  if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    b[key].SessionTime += +a.SessionTime
  } else {
    b[key] = {
      month: a.month,
      year: a.year,
      SessionTime: a.SessionTime
    }
  }
  return b
}, {}))  
}).sort({ month: 1 });
```

```js
const docs = [{
    _id: '60 c3dce8f27cc56bbcf20e94',
    steamID: '76561199105033642',
    displayName: 'username',
    LastJoinDate: 'Sat Jun 12 2021 01:00:04 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
    LastLeaveDate: 'Sat Jun 12 2021 01:00:07 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
    SessionTime: 14,
    UID: '60a6572b98a160df4ffc8b20',
    month: 5,
    year: '2021',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '60 c3ddda65e2073ea162cdfa',
    displayName: 'username',
    LastJoinDate: 'Sat Jun 12 2021 01:00:04 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
    LastLeaveDate: 'Sat Jun 12 2021 01:00:07 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
    SessionTime: 14,
    UID: '60a6572b98a160df4ffc8b20',
    month: 6,
    year: '2021',
    __v: 0,
    steamID: '76561199105033642'
  },
  {
    _id: '60 c3ddda65e2073eea162cdfa',
    displayName: 'username2',
    LastJoinDate: 'Sat Jun 12 2021 01:00:04 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
    LastLeaveDate: 'Sat Jun 12 2021 01:00:07 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
    SessionTime: 24,
    UID: '60a6572b98a160df4ffc8b20',
    month: 6,
    year: '2021',
    __v: 0,
    steamID: '76561199105033642'
  }
]

let ndocs = Object.values(docs.reduce((b, a) => {
  let key = a.month + '' + a.year
  if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    b[key].SessionTime += +a.SessionTime
  } else {
    b[key] = {
      month: a.month,
      year: a.year,
      SessionTime: a.SessionTime
    }
  }
  return b
}, {}))

console.log(ndocs)
```